# Win7 - Can ping Google but not able to browse via browser

Tags: windows-7, internet, browser, internet-connection

I cannot browse any webpage on IE or Chrome. I had scanned the computer and had a few malware on it. Before removing it, the browsers worked fine. I have no proxy settings, DNS is automatic, and the hosts file is empty. I am able to ping Google with no issues, but if I stick the IP in the browser, it goes nowhere.

Comment: What are the "malware" you referred to and how did you clean them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already confirmed that you had "a few malware" on your machine, then I'd highly recommend simply re-installing your OS.

The time you're going to have to spend trying to correct all the devious things the malware might have done, will very quickly be outweighed by the couple of hours it takes to start over from scratch.
Also, there's the risk that you might still not have gotten rid of all the malware yet, and anything you do will be undone a second later.

However, if re-installing is not an option the first step to troubleshoot your problem will be to see exactly where you're connection is being cut. Try see if you can still do DNS look-ups correctly.

Comment: You probably need to state what needs to be reinstalled as 'it' is rather vague.

Comment: Reinstalling windows will be the best option